# Cardinality of Measure 0 sets for a Measurable cardinal

Tags: set-theory

What are the cardinalities of the measure 0 subsets and measure 1 subsets of a measurable cardinal $\kappa$? Are they $<\kappa$ and $\kappa$ respectively? I’m having trouble seeing what measure the subsets of odd and even ordinals have, or subsets of limit ordinals and successor ordinals have. Both pairs of sets appear to me to be disjoint measure 1 sets but that would make the cardinal $\kappa$ have measure 2.

Comment: $A\mapsto\kappa\setminus A$ is a bijection between measure 0 and measure 1 sets

Answer (score -1):

The common definition of a measurable cardinal is an uncountable cardinal $k$ that has a $k$-complete ($k$-closed) free (non-principal) ultrafilter. A filter on $k$ is a family $F$   of subsets of $k$ such that

(i) $k\in F$,

(ii) $\emptyset\not\in F,$

(iii) If $s,t\in F$ then $s\cap t\in F,$

(iiii) If $k\supset t\supset s\in F$ then $t\in F.$

A filter $F$ is free iff $\cap F=\emptyset.$

A filter $F$ on $k$ is an ultrafilter iff it is $\subset$-maximal, which means that if $G$ is also a filter on $k$ and $F\subset G$ then $F=G.$

A filter $F$ is $k$-complete iff  $\cap H\in F$ whenever $\emptyset\ne H\subset F$ and $|H|<k.$

Basic properties of a free ultrafilter $F$ on $k$:

(1) $\forall s\subset k\,(s\in F\iff k\setminus s\not\in F),$

(2). If $s\subset k$ then $s\in F\iff \forall t\in F\,(s\cap t\ne\emptyset).$

(3). If $n\in\Bbb N$ and $S=\{s_1,...,s_n\}$ with $\cup S=k$ then at least one $s_j\in F.$ If also the members of $S$ are pairwise-disjoint then exactly one member of $S$ is in $F.$

(4) $\forall x\in k\,(\{x\}\not\in F).$

If $F$ is a $k$-complete free ultrafilter on $k$ then

(3*) If $\cup S=k$ and $|S|<k$ then at least one member of $S$ is in $F.$ If also the members of $S$ are pairwise-disjoint then exactly one member of $S$ is in $F.$

(4*) If $s\subset k$ and $|s|<k$ then $s\not\in F.$

Now if $k$ is measurable and $F$ is a $k$-complete  free  ultrafilter on  $k,$ we may define a measure $m$ on the subsets of $k$ as the characteristic (indicator)  function of $F$. That is, $m(s)=1$ if $s\in F.$ And $m(s)=0$ if $s\subset k$ and $s\not\in F.$ Observe that if $m(s)=m(t)=1$ then $m(s\cap t)=1$ and $m(k\setminus (s\cap t))=0.$

Some early authors refer to a measurable cardinal as 2-measurable. The terminology "$k$-complete" is standard, although I would prefer "$<k$-complete".A free ultrafilter on $\omega$ is $\omega$-complete, and  a measurable cardinal is an uncountable analog of this.

Comment: BTW if $F$ is a filter on a set  $u$ then $\{u\setminus s: s\in F \}$ is called an ideal on $u.$